# Power set and Cartesian Product of a set python

Tags: python

I am trying to find the cartesian product of two different sets. I can not find anything on the web about cartesian products of sets it's either of list or dictionaries.

Also power set is very confusing.

Neither one of these are in my book I have been using.

Could one of yall point me to the right direction.

Comment: This asks two completely different questions, and is also unclear.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For the Cartesian product, check out [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

For the powerset, [the `itertools` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) also give us a recipe:

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

For example:

```
>>> test = {1, 2, 3}
>>> list(powerset(test))
[(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
>>> list(product(test, test))
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: thank you for the edit it made it a lot more clear I am trying to implement these into my code currently do i need to import itertools ? Thanks Again!

Comment: Yes, you need to import the functions you use from ``itertools``, as with any functions you use from another module.

Comment: powerset might be better defined with `s = set(iterable)`.

Comment: @Darthfett: That would make it a less general solution. But yes, if you are working purely with sets, that would work.