# Python find ALL combinations of a list

Tags: python, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Power set and Cartesian Product of a set python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342939/power-set-and-cartesian-product-of-a-set-python)

scratch the old problem. I figured everything out. Now I have an even crazier issue. Here is what I should be getting:

Input: scoreList(["a", "s", "m", "t", "p"])

output: [['a', 1], ['am', 4], ['at', 2], ['spam', 8]]

This I/O works GREAT, but if I add a 6th element like this:

Input: scoreList(["a", "s", "m", "t", "p", "e"])

The program bugs out like crazy. Please tell me how to fix this. Appreciate any help

My code:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def ind(e,L):
    if L==[] or L=="":
        return 0
    elif L[0]==e:
        return 0
    else:
        return ind(e,L[1:])+1

def letterScore(letter, scorelist):
    if scorelist[0][0] == letter:
        return scorelist[0][1]
    elif (len(scorelist) == 1) and (scorelist[0][0] != letter):
        return 'lol. stop trying to crash my program'
    else:
        return letterScore(letter, scorelist[1:])

scorelist = [ ["a", 1], ["b", 3], ["c", 3], ["d", 2], ["e", 1], ["f", 4], ["g", 2], ["h", 4], ["i", 1], ["j", 8], ["k", 5], ["l", 1], ["m", 3], ["n", 1], ["o", 1], ["p", 3], ["q", 10], ["r", 1], ["s", 1], ["t", 1], ["u", 1], ["v", 4], ["w", 4], ["x", 8], ["y", 4], ["z", 10] ]

def wordScore(S, scorelist):
    if (len(S) == 1):
        return letterScore(S[0],scorelist)
    elif (letterScore(S[0],scorelist) == 'lol. stop trying to crash my program'):
        return 'you really want to crash me, dont you'
    else:
        return letterScore(S[0],scorelist) + wordScore(S[1:], scorelist)


def perm(l):
    sz = len(l)
    if sz <= 1:
        return [l]
    return [p[:i]+[l[0]]+p[i:]
        for i in xrange(sz) for p in perm(l[1:])]


from itertools import combinations, permutations

def findall(my_input):
    return [''.join(p) for x in range(len(my_input)) for c in combinations(my_input, x+1)
            for p in permutations(c)]

d = ["a", "am", "cab", "apple", "at", "bat", "bar", "babble", "can", "foo", "spam", "spammy", "zzyzva"]

def match(lis): 
    return match2(findall(lis))

def match2(lis): 
    if lis == []:
        return []
    elif(len(d) != ind(lis[0],d)):
        return [lis[0]] + match2(lis[1:])
    else:
        return match2(lis[1:])

def scoreList(lis):
    return match3(match(lis))

def match3(lis):
    if (lis == []):
        return []
    else:
        return [[lis[0],wordScore(lis[0],scorelist)]] + match3(lis[1:])
```

Comment: Error message is missing... Please attach

Comment: `<generator object allperm at 0x0000000002AA8438>` is not an error message, it is a textual representation of the generator returned by calling `allperm()`. Iterate over this to retrieve the values.

Comment: As @kindall said just try list(allperm('abc'))

Answer (score 4):

Is this homework, or can you use itertools?

```
>>> my_input = ['a','b','c']
>>> from itertools import combinations, permutations
>>> [''.join(p) for x in range(len(my_input)) for c in combinations(my_input, x+1)
                for p in permutations(c)]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ba', 'ac', 'ca', 'bc', 'cb', 'abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba']
```

Comment: this is part of a hw so I can not use itertools, but this isnt the whole assignment. This is just the part I am having trouble with

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most readable one but here is another solution, using `itertools` and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/716489/8418):

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> inpt = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> sum([map(''.join, list(permutations(inpt, l + 1))) for l in xrange(len(inpt))], [])
['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba']
```

Comment: Be aware that using `sum()` over lists is discouraged as it has quadratic performance

Comment: @gnibbler Yes.. that's why I linked to the other answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The earlier answers show the usage of `itertools` package, but if you don't want to use it (homework is the only reason why you would), I found [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order) algorithm the easiest one to implement.