# Generating permutations of a given length - Python

Tags: python-2.7, permutation, cartesian-product

I want to generate a list of permutations over a given alphabet of length n.
For example, if `n = 3` and the alphabet includes `{A,B}`, output should be: `AAA,AAB,ABA,BAA,ABB,BAB,BBA,BBB`

Comment: Have you tried typing the title of your question in the search box?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342939/power-set-and-cartesian-product-of-a-set-python treats the same topic.

Comment: @deloz: Indeed the accepted answer to the question you mention solves the problem for ``n=2``, but the OP is interested in a general solution for any value of ``n``

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing from the desired output that you want to generate the **cartesian product** of an alphabet with itself repeated `n` times rather than a list of permutations. This admittedly tricky wrapper of [itertools.product()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.product) will do the job just fine:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> def nprod(x, n):
...     args = 'x' + (n-1)*', x'
...     return [''.join(z) for z in eval('itertools.product(%s)' % args)]
...
>>> nprod('AB', 3)
['AAA', 'AAB', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'BAA', 'BAB', 'BBA', 'BBB']
>>> nprod(['1', '2', '3'], 2)
['11', '12', '13', '21', '22', '23', '31', '32', '33']
```

**EDIT:** Oh, silly me!!! I didn't notice in the documentation the optional `repeat` keyword argument :D

```
>>> [''.join(x) for x in itertools.product('AB', repeat=3)]
['AAA', 'AAB', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'BAA', 'BAB', 'BBA', 'BBB']
>>>> [''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(['1', '2', '3'], repeat=2)]
['11', '12', '13', '21', '22', '23', '31', '32', '33']
```

Comment: If you weren't able to use `repeat`, surely `itertools.product(*[x]*n)` would be nicer than using `eval`?